# migrating CLR project to VS 2015 throws C2869 compiler error

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I am converting CLR class Library from vs2010(v4.0) to vs2015. 
I am getting error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\include\system_error(24): error C2869: 'std::errc': has already been defined to be a namespace

I am also unable to add reference in x64, while c# assebly has been build with Any CPU target.

> Could not add a reference
>
> - Targets a higher version of .NET Framework
> - Not a .Net assembly
> - Not a registered ActiveX control

Answer (score 0):

For me, the C2869 error was caused by referencing an assembly that was built using an older version of Visual Studio. I solved the problem with the following steps:

1. Create a dummy cpp file in your project, with just the following lines:

   ## include "Stdafx.h" // if required

   ## include "system_error"
2. Compile just the dummy file and confirm you're seeing the C2869 error.
3. Remove all references from your project, compile just the dummy file and confirm that C2869 disappears.
4. Add your references back in one-by-one and compile the dummy file until C2869 reappears. Now you know which reference is causing the problem.
5. Either rebuild the reference using Visual Studio 2015 (v140* toolset) or find a way to remove the reference.